# How to refactor JS function according to module pattern?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 JS files.

1) The first one is main one and it's organized according to module pattern. It looks as following:

```
"use strict";

var SchemaEditor = (function () {

    /* Private members */
    var black = "black";
    var transparent = "transparent";
    var sd = {
        mode: "pointer", // Set to default mode. Alternatives are "node" and "link", for adding a new node or a new link respectively.
        itemType: "pointer", // Set when user clicks on a node or link button.
        nodeCounter: {}
    };
    var myDiagram;
    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;

    /* Private methods */
    // update the diagram every 250 milliseconds
    function loop() {
        setTimeout(function () { updateStates(); loop(); }, 250);
    }

    // update the value and appearance of each node according to its type and input values
    function updateStates() {
        var oldskip = myDiagram.skipsUndoManager;
        myDiagram.skipsUndoManager = true;
        // do all "input" nodes first
        myDiagram.nodes.each(function (node) {
            if (node.category === "input") {
                doInput(node);
            }
        });
        // now we can do all other kinds of nodes
        myDiagram.nodes.each(function (node) {
            switch (node.category) {
                case "image1": doImage1(node); break;
                case "image2": doImage2(node); break;
                case "image3": doImage3(node); break;
                case "image4": doImage4(node); break;
                case "image5": doImage5(node); break;
                case "image6": doImage6(node); break;
                case "image7": doImage7(node); break;
                case "image8": doImage8(node); break;
                case "image9": doImage9(node); break;
                case "image10": doImage10(node); break;
                case "table": doTable(node); break;
                case "hBar": dohBar(node); break;
            }
        });
        myDiagram.skipsUndoManager = oldskip;
    }

    // update nodes by the specific function for its type
    // determine the color of links coming out of this node based on those coming in and node type
    function doImage1(node) {
        // assume there is just one input link
        // we just need to update the node's Shape.fill
        node.linksConnected.each(function (link) { node.findObject("NODESHAPE1").fill = link.findObject("SHAPE").stroke; });
    }

    function doImage2(node) {
        // assume there is just one input link
        // we just need to update the node's Shape.fill
        node.linksConnected.each(function (link) { node.findObject("NODESHAPE1").fill = link.findObject("SHAPE").stroke; });
    }

    function doImage3(node) {
        // assume there is just one input link
        // we just need to update the node's Shape.fill
        node.linksConnected.each(function (link) { node.findObject("NODESHAPE1").fill = link.findObject("SHAPE").stroke; });
    }

    function doImage4(node) {
        // assume there is just one input link
        // we just need to update the node's Shape.fill
        node.linksConnected.each(function (link) { node.findObject("NODESHAPE1").fill = link.findObject("SHAPE").stroke; });
    }

    function doImage5(node) {
        // assume there is just one input link
        // we just need to update the node's Shape.fill
        node.linksConnected.each(function (link) { node.findObject("NODESHAPE1").fill = link.findObject("SHAPE").stroke; });
    }

    function doImage6(node) {
        // assume there is just one input link
        // we just need to update the node's Shape.fill
        node.linksConnected.each(function (link) { node.findObject("NODESHAPE1").fill = link.findObject("SHAPE").stroke; });
    }

    function doImage7(node) {
        // assume there is just one input link
        // we just need to update the node's Shape.fill
        node.linksConnected.each(function (link) { node.findObject("NODESHAPE1").fill = link.findObject("SHAPE").stroke; });
    }

    function doImage8(node) {
        // assume there is just one input link
        // we just need to update the node's Shape.fill
        node.linksConnected.each(function (link) { node.findObject("NODESHAPE1").fill = link.findObject("SHAPE").stroke; });
    }

    function doImage9(node) {
        // assume there is just one input link
        // we just need to update the node's Shape.fill
        node.linksConnected.each(function (link) { node.findObject("NODESHAPE1").fill = link.findObject("SHAPE").stroke; });
    }

    function doImage10(node) {
        // assume there is just one input link
        // we just need to update the node's Shape.fill
        node.linksConnected.each(function (link) { node.findObject("NODESHAPE1").fill = link.findObject("SHAPE").stroke; });
    }

    function doTable(node) {
        // assume there is just one input link
        // we just need to update the node's Shape.fill
        node.linksConnected.each(function (link) { node.findObject("NODESHAPE1").fill = link.findObject("SHAPE").stroke; });
    }

    function dohBar(node) {
        // assume there is just one input link
        // we just need to update the node's Shape.fill
        node.linksConnected.each(function (link) { node.findObject("NODESHAPE1").fill = link.findObject("SHAPE").stroke; });
    }

    function BarLink() {
        go.Link.call(this);
    }
    go.Diagram.inherit(BarLink, go.Link);

    /** @override */
    BarLink.prototype.getLinkPoint = function (node, port, spot, from, ortho, othernode, otherport) {
        if (node.category === "hBar") {
            var op = go.Link.prototype.getLinkPoint.call(this, othernode, otherport, this.computeSpot(!from), !from, ortho, node, port);
            var r = new go.Rect(port.getDocumentPoint(go.Spot.TopLeft),
                                port.getDocumentPoint(go.Spot.BottomRight));
            var y = (op.y > r.centerY) ? r.bottom : r.top;
            if (op.x < r.left) return new go.Point(r.left, y);
            if (op.x > r.right) return new go.Point(r.right, y);
            return new go.Point(op.x, y);
        } else {
            return go.Link.prototype.getLinkPoint.call(this, node, port, spot, from, ortho, othernode, otherport);
        }
    };

    /** @override */
    BarLink.prototype.getLinkDirection = function (node, port, linkpoint, spot, from, ortho, othernode, otherport) {
        var p = port.getDocumentPoint(go.Spot.Center);
        var op = otherport.getDocumentPoint(go.Spot.Center);
        var below = op.y > p.y;
        return below ? 90 : 270;
    };
    // end BarLink class

    var setMode = function (mode, itemType) {
        myDiagram.startTransaction();
        sd.mode = mode;
        sd.itemType = itemType;
        if (mode === "link") {
            if (itemType === 'default') {
                if (document.getElementById("defaultMode").classList.contains('non-pushed')) {
                    document.getElementById("defaultMode").classList.remove('non-pushed');
                    document.getElementById("defaultMode").classList.add('pushed');
                    document.getElementById("orthoMode").classList.add('non-pushed');
                    document.getElementById("cornerMode").classList.add('non-pushed');
                }
            }
            if (itemType === 'ortho') {
                if (document.getElementById("orthoMode").classList.contains('non-pushed')) {
                    document.getElementById("orthoMode").classList.remove('non-pushed');
                    document.getElementById("orthoMode").classList.add('pushed');
                    document.getElementById("defaultMode").classList.add('non-pushed');
                    document.getElementById("cornerMode").classList.add('non-pushed');
                }
            }
            if (itemType === 'corner') {
                if (document.getElementById("cornerMode").classList.contains('non-pushed')) {
                    document.getElementById("cornerMode").classList.remove('non-pushed');
                    document.getElementById("cornerMode").classList.add('pushed');
                    document.getElementById("defaultMode").classList.add('non-pushed');
                    document.getElementById("orthoMode").classList.add('non-pushed');
                }
            }
            myDiagram.allowLink = true;
            myDiagram.nodes.each(function (n) { n.port.cursor = "pointer"; });
        }
        myDiagram.commitTransaction("mode changed");
    };

    // save a model to and load a model from JSON text, displayed below the Diagram
    var save = function () {
        document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value = myDiagram.model.toJson();
        myDiagram.isModified = false;
    };

    var load = function () {
        myDiagram.model = go.Model.fromJson(document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value);
    };

    function addLinkTemplateMaps() {
        // creates relinkable Links that will avoid crossing Nodes when possible and will jump over other Links in their paths
        myDiagram.linkTemplateMap.add("default",
            $(go.Link,
            {
                relinkableFrom: true, relinkableTo: true,
                selectionAdorned: false, // Links are not adorned when selected so that their color remains visible.
                shadowOffset: new go.Point(0, 0), shadowBlur: 5, shadowColor: "black"
            },
            new go.Binding("isShadowed", "isSelected").ofObject(),
            $(go.Shape,
                { name: "SHAPE", strokeWidth: 2, stroke: black })));

        myDiagram.linkTemplateMap.add("corner",
          $(go.Link,
            { reshapable: true, resegmentable: true, routing: go.Link.AvoidsNodes },
            new go.Binding("points").makeTwoWay(), // TwoWay Binding of Link.points
            $(go.Shape)
          ));

        myDiagram.linkTemplateMap.add("ortho",
            $(BarLink, // subclass defined below
                {
                    routing: go.Link.Orthogonal,
                    relinkableFrom: true,
                    relinkableTo: true,
                    toPortChanged: function (link, oldport, newport) {
                        if (newport instanceof go.Shape) link.path.stroke = newport.fill;
                    }
                },
                $(go.Shape,
                { strokeWidth: 2 })
            ));
    };

    var initSchemaEditor = function () {
        myDiagram = $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
        {
            initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
            allowDrop: true, // Nodes from the Palette can be dropped into the Diagram
            "undoManager.isEnabled": true,
            "grid.visible": true,

            "linkingTool.portGravity": 0, // no snapping while drawing new links
            "linkingTool.doActivate": function () {
                // change the curve of the LinkingTool.temporaryLink
                this.temporaryLink.curve = (sd.itemType === "default") ? go.Link.Normal : go.Link.Orthogonal;
                go.LinkingTool.prototype.doActivate.call(this);
            },
            // override the link creation process
            "linkingTool.insertLink": function (fromnode, fromport, tonode, toport) {
                // to control what kind of Link is created,
                // change the LinkingTool.archetypeLinkData's category
                myDiagram.model.setCategoryForLinkData(this.archetypeLinkData, sd.itemType);
                // also change the text indicating the condition, which the user can edit
                this.archetypeLinkData.text = sd.itemType;
                return go.LinkingTool.prototype.insertLink.call(this, fromnode, fromport, tonode, toport);
            },

            "clickCreatingTool.archetypeNodeData": {}, // enable ClickCreatingTool
            "clickCreatingTool.isDoubleClick": false, // operates on a single click in background
            "clickCreatingTool.canStart": function () { // but only in "node" creation mode
                return sd.mode === "node" && go.ClickCreatingTool.prototype.canStart.call(this);
            },
            "clickCreatingTool.insertPart": function (loc) { // customize the data for the new node
                sd.nodeCounter[sd.itemType] += 1;
                var newNodeId = sd.itemType + sd.nodeCounter[sd.itemType];
                this.archetypeNodeData = {
                    key: newNodeId,
                    category: sd.itemType,
                    label: newNodeId
                };
                return go.ClickCreatingTool.prototype.insertPart.call(this, loc);
            }
        });

        myDiagram.requestUpdate();

        // when the document is modified, add a "*" to the title and enable the "Save" button
        myDiagram.addDiagramListener("Modified", function (e) {
            var button = document.getElementById("saveModel");
            if (button) button.disabled = !myDiagram.isModified;
            var idx = document.title.indexOf("*");
            if (myDiagram.isModified) {
                if (idx < 0) document.title += "*";
            } else {
                if (idx >= 0) document.title = document.title.substr(0, idx);
            }
        });

        myDiagram.model =
          $(go.GraphLinksModel,
            {
                linkFromPortIdProperty: "fromPort", // required information:
                linkToPortIdProperty: "toPort" // identifies data property names
            });

        addLinkTemplateMaps();

        loadNodes();

        myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image1", image1Template);
        myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image2", image2Template);
        myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image3", image3Template);
        myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image4", image4Template);
        myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image5", image5Template);
        myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image6", image6Template);
        myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image7", image7Template);
        myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image8", image8Template);
        myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image9", image9Template);
        myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image10", image10Template);
        myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("table", tableTemplate);
        myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("hBar", hBarTemplate);

        var palette = new go.Palette("palette"); // create a new Palette in the HTML DIV element "palette"

        // share the template map with the Palette
        palette.nodeTemplateMap = myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap;
        //palette.groupTemplateMap = myDiagram.groupTemplateMap;

        palette.model.nodeDataArray = [
            { category: "image1" },
            { category: "image2" },
            { category: "image3" },
            { category: "image4" },
            { category: "image5" },
            { category: "image6" },
            { category: "image7" },
            { category: "image8" },
            { category: "image9" },
            { category: "image10" },
            { category: "table" },
            { category: "hBar" }
        ];

        myDiagram.addDiagramListener("ExternalObjectsDropped", function (e) {
            if (myDiagram.currentTool instanceof go.TextEditingTool) {
                myDiagram.currentTool.acceptText(go.TextEditingTool.LostFocus);
            }
            myDiagram.commandHandler.ungroupSelection();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/Home/GetRandomObjectProperties'
            }).done(function (data) {
                // loop through selection to find table node and populate properties
                myDiagram.selection.each(function (p) {
                    if (p instanceof go.Node && p.category === "table") {
                        var nodedata = p.data;
                        var properties = data.map(function (item) {
                            return { "property_name": item.Item1.toString(), "property_value": item.Item2.toString() };
                        });
                        myDiagram.model.setDataProperty(nodedata, "properties", properties);
                        return;
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        // load the initial diagram
        load();

        // continually update the diagram
        loop();
    };

    /* Public methods */
    return {
        initSchemaEditor: initSchemaEditor,
        setMode: setMode,
        save: save,
        load: load
    };
})();
```

2) The second JS file is not organized according to module pattern and it looks as following:

```
"use strict";

var sharedToolTip;
var image1Template;
var image2Template;
var image3Template;
var image4Template;
var image5Template;
var image6Template;
var image7Template;
var image8Template;
var image9Template;
var image10Template;
var tableTemplate;
var hBarTemplate;

function loadNodes() {
    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;

    // node template helpers
    sharedToolTip =
        $(go.Adornment, "Auto",
            $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle", { fill: "lightyellow" }),
            $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 2 },
                new go.Binding("text", "", function (d) { return d.category; })));

    // define some common property settings
    function nodeStyle() {
        return [
            new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
            new go.Binding("isShadowed", "isSelected").ofObject(),
            {
                selectionAdorned: false,
                shadowOffset: new go.Point(0, 0),
                shadowBlur: 15,
                shadowColor: "blue",
                toolTip: sharedToolTip
            }
        ];
    }

    function portStyle0(input) {
        return {
            desiredSize: new go.Size(3, 3),
            fill: "black",
            fromLinkable: !input,
            toLinkable: input,
            cursor: "pointer"
        };
    }

    function portStyle1() {
        return {
            desiredSize: new go.Size(3, 3),
            fill: "black",
            toLinkable: true,
            cursor: "pointer",
            fromLinkable: true,
            fromSpot: go.Spot.TopBottomSides,
            toSpot: go.Spot.TopBottomSides
        };
    }

    image1Template =
      $(go.Node, "Vertical", nodeStyle(),
        $(go.Picture, "Images/ElectricalElements/Cell_1.svg"),
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle1(),
          { portId: "", alignment: new go.Spot(0.18, 0) })
      );

    image2Template =
      $(go.Node, "Vertical", nodeStyle(),
        $(go.Picture, "Images/ElectricalElements/Cell_2.svg"),
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle1(),
          { portId: "", alignment: new go.Spot(0.33, 0) })
      );

    image3Template =
      $(go.Node, "Vertical", nodeStyle(),
        $(go.Picture, "Images/ElectricalElements/GTU.svg"),
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle1(),
          { portId: "", alignment: new go.Spot(0.215, 0) })
      );

    image4Template =
        $(go.Node, "Vertical", nodeStyle(),
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle0(false),
            { portId: "1", alignment: new go.Spot(0.125, 0) }),
        $(go.Picture, "Images/ElectricalElements/Sec_1.svg"),
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle1(),
            { portId: "2", alignment: new go.Spot(0.125, 0) })
        );

    image5Template =
        $(go.Node, "Vertical", nodeStyle(),
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle0(true),
            { portId: "3", alignment: new go.Spot(0.523, 0) }),
        $(go.Picture, "Images/ElectricalElements/Sec_2.svg"),
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle1(),
            { portId: "4", alignment: new go.Spot(0.523, 0) })
        );

    image6Template =
      $(go.Node, "Vertical", nodeStyle(),
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle0(true),
          { portId: "", alignment: new go.Spot(0.12, 0) }),
        $(go.Picture, "Images/ElectricalElements/Sec_3.svg"),
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle1(),
          { portId: "", alignment: new go.Spot(0.12, 0) })
      );

    image7Template =
      $(go.Node, "Vertical", nodeStyle(),
        $(go.Picture, "Images/ElectricalElements/Tr_1.svg"),
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle1(),
          { portId: "", alignment: new go.Spot(0.42, 0) })
      );

    image8Template =
        $(go.Node, "Vertical", nodeStyle(),
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle1(),
            { portId: "", alignment: new go.Spot(0.59, 0) }),
        $(go.Picture, "Images/ElectricalElements/Tr_2.svg")
        );

    image9Template =
        $(go.Node, "Vertical", nodeStyle(),
            {
                resizable: true,
                resizeObjectName: "SHAPE", selectionObjectName: "SHAPE"
            },
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
            {
                name: "SHAPE",
                fill: transparent,
                width: 60,
                height: 40,
                stroke: black,
                strokeWidth: 1,
                strokeDashArray: [5, 5]
            },
          new go.Binding("desiredSize", "size", go.Size.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Size.stringify))
        );

    image10Template =
      $(go.Node, "Vertical", nodeStyle(),
        $(go.TextBlock,
        {
            text: "text",
            editable: true,
            isMultiline: true
        },
        new go.Binding("text", "text").makeTwoWay())
      );

    tableTemplate =
        $(go.Node, go.Panel.Auto, nodeStyle(),
        $(go.Shape, { fill: "white", stroke: "gray", strokeWidth: 1 }),
        { movable: true },
        new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
        $(go.Panel, "Table",
            new go.Binding("itemArray", "properties"),
            {
                defaultAlignment: go.Spot.Left,
                defaultColumnSeparatorStroke: "black",
                itemTemplate:
                    $(go.Panel, "TableRow",
                        $(go.TextBlock, new go.Binding("text", "property_name"),
                        { column: 0, margin: 1, font: "bold 7pt sans-serif" }),
                        $(go.TextBlock, new go.Binding("text", "property_value"),
                        { column: 1, margin: 1 })
                    )
            },
            $(go.Panel, "TableRow",
                { isPanelMain: true },
                $(go.TextBlock, "Name",
                { column: 0, margin: new go.Margin(1, 1, 0, 1), font: "bold 7pt sans-serif" }),
                $(go.TextBlock, "Value",
                { column: 1, margin: new go.Margin(1, 1, 0, 1), font: "bold 7pt sans-serif" })
            ),
            $(go.RowColumnDefinition,
            { row: 0, background: "lightgray" }),
            $(go.RowColumnDefinition,
            { row: 1, separatorStroke: "black" })
        )
    );

    hBarTemplate =
      $(go.Node,
        new go.Binding("location", "location", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
        {
            layerName: "Background",
            // special resizing: just at the ends
            resizable: true, resizeObjectName: "SHAPE",
            resizeAdornmentTemplate:
              $(go.Adornment, "Spot",
                $(go.Placeholder),
                $(go.Shape, // left resize handle
                  {
                      alignment: go.Spot.Left, cursor: "col-resize",
                      desiredSize: new go.Size(6, 6), fill: "lightblue", stroke: "dodgerblue"
                  }),
                $(go.Shape, // right resize handle
                  {
                      alignment: go.Spot.Right, cursor: "col-resize",
                      desiredSize: new go.Size(6, 6), fill: "lightblue", stroke: "dodgerblue"
                  })),
            rotatable: true
        },
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
          {
              name: "SHAPE",
              fill: "black", stroke: null, strokeWidth: 0,
              width: 60, height: 5,
              minSize: new go.Size(50, 5),
              maxSize: new go.Size(Infinity, 5)
          },
          new go.Binding("desiredSize", "size", go.Size.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Size.stringify),
          new go.Binding("fill"),
          { portId: "", toLinkable: true })
      );
};
```

I call the function loadNodes from second JS file in main JS file and it works.

But, when I've tried to organize the second JS file according to module pattern it stopped working.

I've tried the folowing:

1) The main file:

```
...

NodeRepository.loadNodes();

myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image1", NodeRepository.image1Template);
myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image2", NodeRepository.image2Template);
myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image3", NodeRepository.image3Template);
myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image4", NodeRepository.image4Template);
myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image5", NodeRepository.image5Template);
myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image6", NodeRepository.image6Template);
myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image7", NodeRepository.image7Template);
myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image8", NodeRepository.image8Template);
myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image9", NodeRepository.image9Template);
myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image10", NodeRepository.image10Template);
myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("table", NodeRepository.tableTemplate);
myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("hBar", NodeRepository.hBarTemplate);

...
```

2) The second file:

```
"use strict";

var NodeRepository = (function () {
    var sharedToolTip;
    var image1Template;
    var image2Template;
    var image3Template;
    var image4Template;
    var image5Template;
    var image6Template;
    var image7Template;
    var image8Template;
    var image9Template;
    var image10Template;
    var tableTemplate;
    var hBarTemplate;

    function loadNodes() {
        var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
        ...
    };

    return {
        image1Template: image1Template,
        image2Template: image2Template,
        image3Template: image3Template,
        image4Template: image4Template,
        image5Template: image5Template,
        image6Template: image6Template,
        image7Template: image7Template,
        image8Template: image8Template,
        image9Template: image9Template,
        image10Template: image10Template,
        tableTemplate: tableTemplate,
        hBarTemplate: hBarTemplate,
        loadNodes: loadNodes
    };
})();
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? How are the files loaded?

Comment: It's MVC 5 application and the JS files were loaded in standard way:     @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/schema_editor.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/node-repository.js") in layout file.

Comment: An there are errors in main file. All these things: NodeRepository.image1Template, NodeRepository.image2Template... in:         myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image1", NodeRepository.image1Template);
        myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("image2", NodeRepository.image2Template); ... are "undefined".

Comment: Sorry can't help. Your question is tagged javascript but has little to do with javascript itself, you might want to retag.

Comment: Ok. Retag to what?

Comment: I've fixed the issue in the meantime.

Comment: Good, I suggest you explain how you did in an answer so it may help others later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
"use strict";

var NodeRepository = (function () {

    var sharedToolTip;
    var image1Template;
    var image2Template;
    var image3Template;
    var image4Template;
    var image5Template;
    var image6Template;
    var image7Template;
    var image8Template;
    var image9Template;
    var image10Template;
    var tableTemplate;
    var hBarTemplate;

    function image1Public() {
        return image1Template;
    }
    function image2Public() {
        return image2Template;
    }
    function image3Public() {
        return image3Template;
    }
    function image4Public() {
        return image4Template;
    }
    function image5Public() {
        return image5Template;
    }
    function image6Public() {
        return image6Template;
    }
    function image7Public() {
        return image7Template;
    }
    function image8Public() {
        return image8Template;
    }
    function image9Public() {
        return image9Template;
    }
    function image10Public() {
        return image10Template;
    }
    function image11Public() {
        return tableTemplate;
    }
    function image12Public() {
        return hBarTemplate;
    }

    function loadNodes() {
        var $ = go.GraphObject.make;

        // node template helpers
        sharedToolTip =
            $(go.Adornment, "Auto",
                $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle", { fill: "lightyellow" }),
                $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 2 },
                    new go.Binding("text", "", function (d) { return d.category; })));

        // define some common property settings
        function nodeStyle() {
            return [
                new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
                new go.Binding("isShadowed", "isSelected").ofObject(),
                {
                    selectionAdorned: false,
                    shadowOffset: new go.Point(0, 0),
                    shadowBlur: 15,
                    shadowColor: "blue",
                    toolTip: sharedToolTip
                }
            ];
        }

        function portStyle0(input) {
            return {
                desiredSize: new go.Size(3, 3),
                fill: "black",
                fromLinkable: !input,
                toLinkable: input,
                cursor: "pointer"
            };
        }

        function portStyle1() {
            return {
                desiredSize: new go.Size(3, 3),
                fill: "black",
                toLinkable: true,
                cursor: "pointer",
                fromLinkable: true,
                fromSpot: go.Spot.TopBottomSides,
                toSpot: go.Spot.TopBottomSides
            };
        }

        image1Template =
          $(go.Node, "Vertical", nodeStyle(),
            $(go.Picture, "Images/ElectricalElements/Cell_1.svg"),
            $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle1(),
              { portId: "", alignment: new go.Spot(0.18, 0) })
          );

        image2Template =
          $(go.Node, "Vertical", nodeStyle(),
            $(go.Picture, "Images/ElectricalElements/Cell_2.svg"),
            $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle1(),
              { portId: "", alignment: new go.Spot(0.33, 0) })
          );

        image3Template =
          $(go.Node, "Vertical", nodeStyle(),
            $(go.Picture, "Images/ElectricalElements/GTU.svg"),
            $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle1(),
              { portId: "", alignment: new go.Spot(0.215, 0) })
          );

        image4Template =
            $(go.Node, "Vertical", nodeStyle(),
            $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle0(false),
                { portId: "1", alignment: new go.Spot(0.125, 0) }),
            $(go.Picture, "Images/ElectricalElements/Sec_1.svg"),
            $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle1(),
                { portId: "2", alignment: new go.Spot(0.125, 0) })
            );

        image5Template =
            $(go.Node, "Vertical", nodeStyle(),
            $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle0(true),
                { portId: "3", alignment: new go.Spot(0.523, 0) }),
            $(go.Picture, "Images/ElectricalElements/Sec_2.svg"),
            $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle1(),
                { portId: "4", alignment: new go.Spot(0.523, 0) })
            );

        image6Template =
          $(go.Node, "Vertical", nodeStyle(),
            $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle0(true),
              { portId: "", alignment: new go.Spot(0.12, 0) }),
            $(go.Picture, "Images/ElectricalElements/Sec_3.svg"),
            $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle1(),
              { portId: "", alignment: new go.Spot(0.12, 0) })
          );

        image7Template =
          $(go.Node, "Vertical", nodeStyle(),
            $(go.Picture, "Images/ElectricalElements/Tr_1.svg"),
            $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle1(),
              { portId: "", alignment: new go.Spot(0.42, 0) })
          );

        image8Template =
            $(go.Node, "Vertical", nodeStyle(),
            $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle1(),
                { portId: "", alignment: new go.Spot(0.59, 0) }),
            $(go.Picture, "Images/ElectricalElements/Tr_2.svg")
            );

        image9Template =
            $(go.Node, "Vertical", nodeStyle(),
                {
                    resizable: true,
                    resizeObjectName: "SHAPE", selectionObjectName: "SHAPE"
                },
            $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
                {
                    name: "SHAPE",
                    fill: transparent,
                    width: 60,
                    height: 40,
                    stroke: black,
                    strokeWidth: 1,
                    strokeDashArray: [5, 5]
                },
              new go.Binding("desiredSize", "size", go.Size.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Size.stringify))
            );

        image10Template =
          $(go.Node, "Vertical", nodeStyle(),
            $(go.TextBlock,
            {
                text: "text",
                editable: true,
                isMultiline: true
            },
            new go.Binding("text", "text").makeTwoWay())
          );

        tableTemplate =
            $(go.Node, go.Panel.Auto, nodeStyle(),
            $(go.Shape, { fill: "white", stroke: "gray", strokeWidth: 1 }),
            { movable: true },
            new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
            $(go.Panel, "Table",
                new go.Binding("itemArray", "properties"),
                {
                    defaultAlignment: go.Spot.Left,
                    defaultColumnSeparatorStroke: "black",
                    itemTemplate:
                        $(go.Panel, "TableRow",
                            $(go.TextBlock, new go.Binding("text", "property_name"),
                            { column: 0, margin: 1, font: "bold 7pt sans-serif" }),
                            $(go.TextBlock, new go.Binding("text", "property_value"),
                            { column: 1, margin: 1 })
                        )
                },
                $(go.Panel, "TableRow",
                    { isPanelMain: true },
                    $(go.TextBlock, "Name",
                    { column: 0, margin: new go.Margin(1, 1, 0, 1), font: "bold 7pt sans-serif" }),
                    $(go.TextBlock, "Value",
                    { column: 1, margin: new go.Margin(1, 1, 0, 1), font: "bold 7pt sans-serif" })
                ),
                $(go.RowColumnDefinition,
                { row: 0, background: "lightgray" }),
                $(go.RowColumnDefinition,
                { row: 1, separatorStroke: "black" })
            )
        );

        hBarTemplate =
          $(go.Node,
            new go.Binding("location", "location", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
            {
                layerName: "Background",
                // special resizing: just at the ends
                resizable: true, resizeObjectName: "SHAPE",
                resizeAdornmentTemplate:
                  $(go.Adornment, "Spot",
                    $(go.Placeholder),
                    $(go.Shape, // left resize handle
                      {
                          alignment: go.Spot.Left, cursor: "col-resize",
                          desiredSize: new go.Size(6, 6), fill: "lightblue", stroke: "dodgerblue"
                      }),
                    $(go.Shape, // right resize handle
                      {
                          alignment: go.Spot.Right, cursor: "col-resize",
                          desiredSize: new go.Size(6, 6), fill: "lightblue", stroke: "dodgerblue"
                      })),
                rotatable: true
            },
            $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
              {
                  name: "SHAPE",
                  fill: "black", stroke: null, strokeWidth: 0,
                  width: 60, height: 5,
                  minSize: new go.Size(50, 5),
                  maxSize: new go.Size(Infinity, 5)
              },
              new go.Binding("desiredSize", "size", go.Size.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Size.stringify),
              new go.Binding("fill"),
              { portId: "", toLinkable: true })
          );
    };

    return {
        image1Public: image1Public,
        image2Public: image2Public,
        image3Public: image3Public,
        image4Public: image4Public,
        image5Public: image5Public,
        image6Public: image6Public,
        image7Public: image7Public,
        image8Public: image8Public,
        image9Public: image9Public,
        image10Public: image10Public,
        image11Public: image11Public,
        image12Public: image12Public,
        loadNodes: loadNodes
    };

})();
```